$\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\cos(\sqrt{xy})-1}{y}$ using Taylor series
To evaluate the following limit
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\cos(\sqrt{xy})-1}{y}$$
I tried to use the fact
$$\sqrt{xy}\leq\frac{x+y}{2}$$
but it didn't work as I thought. My friend said I could use the Taylor Series
$$\cos(x)\sim1-\frac{x^{2}}{2}\Rightarrow\cos(\sqrt{xy})\sim1-\frac{\sqrt{xy}^2}{2}=1-\frac{xy}{2}$$
Hence,
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\cos(\sqrt{xy})-1}{y}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{1-\dfrac{xy}{2}-1}{y}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}-\frac{x}{2}=0$$
But, to be honest, I never used Taylor series to evaluate limits. Is this correct or am I missing something here?

It's rough, but the conclusion is correct. The symbol $\sim$ has the precise meaning that the ratio converges to $1$. But here it's not obvious from the $\sim$ relation that the limit has the form you wrote. You really need that $\cos(x) = 1 - x^2/2 + o(x^2)$, so that $\cos((xy)^{1/2}) = 1 - xy/2 + o(xy)$, $\frac{\cos((xy)^{1/2}) - 1}{y} = -x/2 + o(x)$.

@Kakashi but why can I conclude the limit goes to $0$ from $-x/2+o(x)$?

@Kakashi also, may I say $\frac{O(x^4y^4)}{x^2y^2}=O(x^2y^2)$?

Use the definitions of $o$ and $O$. For example, $o(x) \subset o(1)$ since if $f(x)/x \to 0$ then $f(x) \to 0$.

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\cos(\sqrt{xy})-1}{y} 
\\= \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{(1 - \frac{xy}{2!} + \frac{(xy)^{2}}{4!} + \cdots)-1}{y} 
\\= \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{- \frac{xy}{2!} + \frac{(xy)^{2}}{4!} + \cdots}{y} 
\\= \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}- \frac{x}{2!} + \frac{yx^{2}}{4!} + \cdots = 0$$
